# Representation of Symmetry group

Tags: quantum-mechanics, group-representations

Suppose the SE $\boldsymbol{H}\psi=E\psi$ describes a closed system and $G$ is a symmetry group of the system. Then any transformation in $G$ leaves the form of the SE invariant. It seems plausible to state that the unitary operators corresponding to various transformations in $G$ in a representation of $G$ on the full Hilbert Space of physical states of the system would commute with the Hamiltonian. I am trying to show this more rigorously, but can't seem to fix the math involved. Any indication as to how we could show this would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g\in G$ (more strictly let $g$ be an element of a unitary representation of $G$ on our Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$) then $g$ leaves the SE invariant:

$${\mathbf H} g\psi = Eg\psi$$

Since $E$ is just a number we can commute $E$ and $g$ freely so:

$${\mathbf H} g\psi = gE\psi$$

Left multiplying the original symmetry equation by $g$ gives:

$$g{\mathbf H}\psi = gE\psi$$

Hence:

$$g{\mathbf H}\psi = {\mathbf H}g\psi$$

Now in a finite dimensional Hilbert space the eigenvectors of ${\mathbf H}$ are a basis for the space so, by linearity, we are justified in saying that $\mathbf H$ and $g$ commute on the whole space. In infinite dimensional spaces we can (often) do something similar but it will, in general, depend on the properties of ${\mathrm H}$. In the case where ${\mathrm H}$ is defined everywhere on ${\mathbb H}$ then it is bounded and the result still follows.

Unfortunately most Hamiltonians of interest in quantum mechanics aren't bounded so we have to get a bit more technical. The most general setting I am confident the result follows in is where $\mathrm H$ has a compact inverse. I *think* we are still fine as long as the spectrum of $\mathrm H$ is non-empty but I could very well be wrong.